# How to create Content MathML for screen-reader accuracy (WCAG 2.0 compliance)

Tags: latex, accessibility, mathml, wcag2.0, epub3

I work in publishing, and I am trying to use MathML to display math in XML-based EPUB 3 publications. I am able to generate Presentation MathML using Microsoft Word's Equation Builder.  However, accessibility standards require hidden Content MathML that I don't think can be generated.

The following link shows an example of how screen readers / assistive technology would read an equation with and without Content MathML:
[Presentation vs Content MathML](https://archive.cnx.org/contents/064e85de-6ba2-43ab-bbd0-fd7daf5a6c34@1/presentation-mathml-versus-content-mathml)

Does anyone have recommendations for solving this issue?  Are there alternatives to writing Content MathML by hand for every equation?

Comment: Screenreaders have very limited support for Presentation MathML (only VoiceOver and JAWS have partial of support), no screenreader supports Content MathML, epub3 does not require support for Content MathML. And of course browser support for Presentation MathML is very partial in only Firefox and Safari (and not maintained); no browser supports Content MathML. You might want to check [speech-rule-engine](https://github.com/zorkow/speech-rule-engine).